# Is there any alternative for the Redactor plugin in Craft 3?

Tags: craft3, plugins, redactor, richtext, editor

The Redactor plugin not working well for me. So I am in need of another good plugin for an editor that supports HTML, image, video, etc.

Please advise me about this.

Comment: Just to understand better what you need, what is problematic for you in the Redactor plugin ? Is it lacking a feature , or not working as espected ? The plugin (https://github.com/craftcms/redactor) can be forked and improved to suit your needs better.

Comment: My standard.json is like below: `{
    "buttons": ["html", "format", "bold", "italic", "lists", "link", "file","unorderedlist","orderedlist","image","video","table"],
    "plugins": ["fullscreen"],
    "toolbarFixed": true,
     "replaceTags": false,
    "fileUpload": "fichiers/",
    "script": true,
    "paragraphize": false,
    "replaceDivs": false,
    "linebreaks": true,
    "enterKey": false,
    
}`    , But when taking redactor fields, it does not showing video, image etc.

Answer (score 1):

Rakhi, based on your comment on the question, you're missing the `video` and `imagemanager` in the plugins array.

Example:

```
"plugins": [
    "alignment",
    "fontcolor",
    "video",
    "imagemanager",
    "table",
    "fullscreen"
],
```

Read more about it [Here](https://github.com/craftcms/redactor) and [Here](https://imperavi.com/redactor/plugins/)